# Texture Paint, problem encounter every time I reopen my blender file

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I am still quite new to blender texture paint, and I have been following a tutorial on how to texture paint with layer. The problem I'm encountering here is every time I close and reopen my blender file the texture paint looks complete off(I have double check and save all image before closing).

An image before I close my blender(Apologies for the amateurish painting, I have been trying to solve and pinpoint the problem through retracing my steps)

[image]

Here, is the image after I close and reopen blender, as you can see the stroke end up with a "water-stained" outline.

[image]

My node set up  for the texture paint.
[image]

I'm really confuse on what is causing the problem, or is this method which require the artist to finish everything in one go. An advise to fix this problem is greatly appreciated.

*Edited:
Not sure if this is important information, but this is the setting that I using when creating the "layer" for image texture.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the alpha is converted to black (or white ?) when the texture is saved to disk, are you using PNG textures with RGBA channels ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using PNG texture with RGBA channel, is that the cause of the problem?

Comment: I don't really know, I just saw that the problem is located on the falloff area of your brush, and since your problem appeared when you saved the image to disk, I guess some information is lost on the way...

Comment: Assuming that is the cause, is there a way to prevent it ?

Comment: I don't see a 'water stain', I see a bump as if the texture is also plugged into a vector bump node output - is this the only material applied to the mesh?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I "unplugged" all the normal/bump map from the principled bsdf. the problem still remain whenever i reopen my file.